# How to have the label and input text within the same container

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to recreate this textfield design

[image]

As you can see the label/hint text is centered when it is not focused and once in focus, the input text and the label/hint text are also centered within the border.

What I tried to recreate this design is first to create the textfield, remove all the borders, and wrap it with a container, and finally play with content padding but I either get text input text off-centered or I get the label/hint text off-centered.

Images below show how the label/hint is off-centered
[image]

BUT when in focus
[image]

Here sample code

```
              Container(
                height: 60,
                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                  start: width * 0.038,
                  end: width * 0.038,
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                      color: state.hasError
                          ? Constant.errorColor
                          : Constant.greyColor,
                      width: 1),
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                ),
                child: TextField(
                  inputFormatters: inputFormatter,
                  controller: controller,
                  onSubmitted: onSubmitted,
                  onChanged: state.didChange,
                  focusNode: focusNode,
                  textInputAction: textInputAction,
                  keyboardType: keyboard,
                  obscureText: obscure,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: label,
                    alignLabelWithHint: true,
                    labelStyle: Constant.hintText.copyWith(
                      color: state.hasError
                          ? Constant.errorColor
                          : Constant.greyColor,
                      fontSize: 14,
                    ),
                    hintText: hint,
                    hintStyle: Constant.hintText.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    contentPadding: null,
                    // contentPadding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                    //   bottom: 7.5,
                    // ),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom text box:

```
Container(
    Column(
       children: [
         Text("insert label text", textAlign: TextAlign.start)
         TextField(
           ...
           // no labelText
           // remove decorations
         )
      ]
   )
);
```

Comment: Yeah I could but the label will always be visible when the textfield is not in focus or not.

Comment: The Text can be wrapped with a visibility widget. If the textfield is in focus you can adjust the boolean for the visibility. 

The animation itself (in regards to moving the label)might be a little complex if you create one from scratch.